# How can I use Int.min and Int.max on a switch statement?

Tags: swift, switch-statement

[image] I'm very new to coding on swift < 1 year... So, I accept I need help... In this exercise an error message pops up saying 'expected ':' after case'

my code here:

```
let Temperature = 65
switch Temperature {

case Int.min <.. 65:
print(“the temperature is too low”)

case 65...75:
print(“the temperature is perfect”)

case 75>..Int.max:
print(“the temperature is too high”)

default:
print (“please set a temperature value”)
```

Comment: What issue are you having with the code you posted? Be clear and specific. And please [edit] your question, don't post comments.

Comment: Okay I know I can use  Int.min and Int.max  on a switch statement, but I don't know how

Comment: The code you posted looks like you are using it. As I said, [edit] your question with specific details. What issues are you having with the code you posted?

Comment: That code seems fine, other than the fact that you could just write `...64` and `76...` instead. So what's the issue you're having?

Comment: The question is predicated on a bug in the first place, there are no default operators `<..` or `>..` or `..>`, only the [range operators](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH6-ID73) for closed range (`...`) or half-open range (`..<`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that there is no ranges like `<..`, `>..` or `..>`, you can only use [CountableClosedRange](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/countableclosedrange)  `...` or [CountableRange](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/countablerange)  `..<` and if you are coding in Swift 4 or later there is no need to use Int.min or Int.max you can simply omit it and use partial range operators.

```
switch Temperature {
case ..<65:
    print("the temperature is too low")
case 65...75:
    print("the temperature is perfect")
case 75...:
    print("the temperature is too high")
default:
    break
}
```

If you are using Swift 3 or earlier you can do as follow:

```
switch Temperature {
case .min ..< 65:
    print("the temperature is too low")
case 65 ... 75:
    print("the temperature is perfect")
case 75 ... .max:
    print("the temperature is too high")
default:
    break
}
```

Comment: all right, tried that but still doesn't compile, now it shows error: ...< is not an unary operator.. don't know what this means now...

Comment: @ChristianO.Vargas What is your Xcode version? Note that it should be two dots plus the less than operator `..<`

Comment: the version is 8.3.3 , Im doing it exactly as your suggested code above but the error keeps appearing

Comment: Like I said parcial range operator it is only available for Swift 4 ( Xcode 9 or later) I will post Swift 3 version (Xcode 8.x)